# How to delete terms within Drupal taxonomy module?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, vocabulary

If terms (admin OR user created) are duplicates, I don't see a way to delete them from within the Drupal browser interface.

This becomes a problem during, say, adding products to an ecommerce site that breaks their products up into categories. The person adding the product sees multiple duplicate categories (which are terms within a Vocabulary) and doesn't know which one to choose.

You can delete ALL terms in a lists by virtue of deleting a Vocabulary, but that's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the page where you can edit the term, the is also a option to delete the term.

The url to the page above is `admin/content/taxonomy/edit/term/[tid]`, where tid is the term id for the term you want to delete. You can Click your way to it by:

1. Going to the taxonomy section
2. Click the `list items` in the select vocabulary.
3. Click the edit link for the taxonomy terms you want to delete.
4. Click the delete button.